# Creating a new entry from data from a different collection (MongoDb)

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to create a new entry based on an entry from an other collection. I have some default fields.

In sql it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO collection1 (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field_1, field_2, "manualValue" as field3 FROM collection2
```

Ofc in mongo there wouldn't be any destination fields. And in my case field_1 would be an array.
A collegue said it should be done with $facet but I don't really see how.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator which can work the same way as `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT` in SQL syntax. Basically it takes your aggregation pipeline and redirects it to specified collection but there is one caveat: it creates new collection or replaces existing, so you can't "append" you results to existing collection. Transalting your SQL to Mongo:

```
db.collection2.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            field_1: 1,
            field_2: 1,
            field_3: "manualValue"
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "collection1"
    }
])
```